# How to get Sencha Touch application working on Blackberry devices

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, blackberry-webworks

I have sencha touch application it's working fine . 
But now i want to run this sencha touch application on blackberry simulator or device. 
I'm not getting where to put model,view, controller class of sencha application.
How to put sencha mvc application in the blackberry phonegap application.
i read many past but did not clearly what to do.
Please suggest me procedure how to do  this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok @user1489812 here we go,

1. Creating structure something like this

[image]

If you only need a jQuery mobile put a folder how to show picture, else NOT.

2.Into index.html file put all references to Sencha Touch 2, like this .js and .css file.

3.Launch your app on blackberry browser `http://localhost:8080/your_name_project/your_name_app.html` and ready.

All above you can getting app into blackberry simulator.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: This structure we used in sencha project. but the problem is now i want to use is project in blackberry phonegap project. For that i want to know how to put sencha project in blackberry phonegap project and make it work. Is phonegap build of sencha project needed? if yes how we camn make phonegap build of sencha project?.

Comment: hey hekoMobile,.. i am using packaged sencha touch 2 application in blackberry webworks application. and i am getting only white screen on the blackberry simulator and not any error. If i check on this on chrome browser its working fine.Please tellwhat i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Show me how do you doing and I replicate it in my BB simulator. :)

Comment: I have a sencha application and i packaging this sencha application using command (sencha app build package). And i created a blackberry phonegap application in blackberry phonegap application i created www folder and i putting package sencha application in www folder. Then i buliding blackberry app and run . It showing white screen. my index.html code u can see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605816/running-sencha-phonegap-blackberry

Comment: I see, try you to change the path, like so `../sdk/sencha-touch.js` etc, etc, these helped if not let me know. :)