# running sencha + phonegap + blackberry

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, blackberry-webworks

I runing sencha application using blackberry phonegap.for this steps i following;
1. make build of sencha application using command(sencha app build package)
2.created blackberry phonegap project and under this created www folder
3. copied all files from sench build and paste in the www folder
4. run blackberry phonegap project 
after running project i get white screen. can please anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

my index.html code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML><html manifest="" lang="en-US">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <title>RetailBanking</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   (function(h){
       function f(c, d){

          document.write('<meta name="' + c + '" content="' + d + '">')
           }
          if ("undefined" === typeof g) 
         var g = h.Ext = {};
           g.blink = function(c){
                 var d = c.js || [], c = c.css || [], b, e, a;
                  f("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-              
                 scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
              f("apple-mobile-web-app-capable", "yes");
              f("apple-touch-fullscreen", "yes");
            for (b = 0, e = c.length; b < e; b++) {

      a = c[b], "string" != typeof a && (a = a.path), document.write('<link             
         rel="stylesheet" href="' + a + '">');
         }
           for (b = 0, e = d.length; b <e; b++) {

             a = d[b], "string" != typeof a && (a = a.path), document.write('<script 
            src="' + a + '"><\/script>')
         }
       }
            })(this);
          ;
      Ext.blink({
         "id": "0e9adf70-bf82-11e1-97b4-2d0be393dffb",
        "js": [{
         "path": "cordova-1.9.0.js",
          "type": "js"
           }, {
          "path": "sdk/sencha-touch.js",
          "type": "js"
                }, {
          "path": "sdk/sencha-touch-all.js",
             "type": "js"
                   }, {
                "path": "Messages.js",
                  "type": "js"
                             }, {
                         "path": "constants.js",
                                "type": "js"
                            }, {
                            "path": "math-uuid.js",
                               "type": "js"
                              }, {
                              "path": "app.js",
                             "update": "delta",
                                 "type": "js"
                                       }],
                                   "css": [{
                            "path": "resources/css/app.css",
                                 "update": "delta",
                                   "type": "css"
                              }]
                              })
                </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
           </script>
          </head>
          <body>

          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please response . I needed help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the proper access elements in your config file. You will need to whitelist the maps.google.com domain to allow your app to use their resources. The PhoneGap website has [more information](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide_blackberry) on whitelisting domains.